# SQL Server: How can I format a float as a string, without commas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, format, sql-server-2017

I'm currently using the format `'N99'`, which is great, except that it adds commas.

Is there a way to specify no commas in the format?
Or do I have to use `REPLACE` to remove the commas myself? (Slower, but acceptable.)

**EDIT:** I need to use the `FORMAT` function, to meet my requirements.

[image]

Comment: What is `N99` format?

Comment: @saAction It seems to provide 99 digits to the right of the decimal point, regardless how many digits are to the left of the decimal point. That's all I know about it. It matters when I start using very small numbers, that need lots of decimal digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `Format` function for this format

It can be done like this :

```
declare @num as float
set @num=21739130.43478260

select format(@num, N'#.##############################');
-- output : 21739130.4347826
```

There are many ways to do this:

Convert function :

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), Cast(@num as decimal(38, 2)))
--output : 21739130.43

SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @num,128)
--output : 21739130.4347826090000000
```

String function :

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(@num, 25, 99))
--output : 2.1739130434782609e+007
```

Comment: `FORMAT ( @num , N'#.######' )` works perfectly! It even removes the trailing zeroes, which is even better. (Of course I'll end up using a lot of #'s, but that's fine.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`str` function also convert float to string, not sure it fulfil your requirement or not

```
 STR(1000000000E0/46E0,len(STR(1000000000E0/46E0))+10,16)

 output=21739130.43478260900
```

and replace function works for your requirement

```
select  replace(format(1000000000E0/46E0,N'N99'), ',', '')
```

output

```
21739130.434782600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It does get rid of the commas. Unfortunately, it does not fulfill my other requirements. But it is a good answer to this question, and may help other people with the same problem.